# hierarchyid SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

I want to store the regional information of a customer, for this, I will create the following tables

1. Country
2. State
3. District

But using `hierarchyid` in SQL Server 2008, I think I can store the information in a single table called Region. Am I right?

Comment: You may be able to do so, but does it make sense as far as your querying of it goes?

Comment: http://raufdasooqi.blogspot.com/2011/04/hierachyid-in-sql-server-2008.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Country, State and District` share the same columns than a tree like structure would fit your needs.
You could use `hierarchyid` or just a `self referencing foreign key`

Comment: then how to get all districts under a state (all the entities shown as drop down lists)

Comment: You would have to use a recursive CTE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx